# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header even thou other requests from the same domain are working

Tags: php, cors

I have a strange error, with No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header. I understand that I have to give some permission the origin domain(client) to be able to access the server and that works fine with some other requests I make. But when it comes to one other function to call, it says No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header only.

I have my client hosted in heroku and server in godaddy...

This is the function when that error shows:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $ffSpending = new FriendsFamilySpending();
    $ffSpending->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $ffSpending->team_id = Auth::user()->student->team_id;
    $ffSpending->management_units = $request->input('management_units');
    $ffSpending->sales_units = $request->input('sales_units');
    $ffSpending->product_units = $request->input('product_units');
    $ffSpending->ip_units = $request->input('ip_units');

    $ffSpendingRules = array(
        'management_units' => 'required',
        'sales_units' => 'required',
        'product_units' => 'required',
        'ip_units' => 'required'
    );

    $ffSpendingValidator = \Validator::make($ffSpending->getAttributes(), $ffSpendingRules);

    if ($ffSpendingValidator->passes()) {


        $team = Team::find($ffSpending->team_id);
        $currentBalance = $this->teamService->checkBalance($team);

        //Baseline costs
        $BASELINE = FriendsFamilySpending::BASELINE;
        //Get Prices for each unit
        $IP_ONE_TIME_COST = OperationalExpensePrice::getPrice(OperationalExpense::IP, $request->input('ip_units'), OperationalExpenseSerie::FF);//one-time IP costs
        $MANAGEMENT = OperationalExpensePrice::getPrice(OperationalExpense::MANAGEMENT, $request->input('management_units'), OperationalExpenseSerie::FF);
        $SALES = OperationalExpensePrice::getPrice(OperationalExpense::SALES, $request->input('sales_units'), OperationalExpenseSerie::FF);
        $PRODUCT = OperationalExpensePrice::getPrice(OperationalExpense::PRODUCT, $request->input('product_units'), OperationalExpenseSerie::FF);

        //Monthly Costs
        $quartlyCosts = $BASELINE + $MANAGEMENT + $SALES + $PRODUCT;

        $newBalance = $currentBalance;
        $workingMoney = $newBalance - $IP_ONE_TIME_COST;

        $minimumMonth = 12; // the minimum amount of time they must be able to afford (Staging Day  = 12 months)
        //Calculate how many months they (team) can survive
        $survivingMonths = 0;
        while ($workingMoney >= $quartlyCosts) {
            $workingMoney = $workingMoney - $quartlyCosts; //deduct monthly costs from the current working money
            $survivingMonths = $survivingMonths + 3; // quartly spending
            if ($survivingMonths > 24) { // team survives the whole staging and deal day
                break;
            }
        }

        // month to minute - Conversation ratio
        $monthToMinute = 6.25; // (75min / 12month) = 6.25min a month
        $totalMinutes = $survivingMonths * $monthToMinute;
        $minMinutes = 75; //the minimum amount of time they must be able to afford

        //Check if team makes it till the deal day
        if ($survivingMonths < $minimumMonth) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'With your current spending plan, you will not make it to deal day. Please try again with less spending plan. Currently you run out of money after ' . $totalMinutes . ' minutes. You have to survive at least 75 minutes."', 'success' => false, 'status' => 500, 'data' => null]);
        }

        $ffSpendingRes = $this->ffSpendingService->save($ffSpending);
        if ($ffSpendingRes) {
            $this->ffSpendingService->score(Auth::user()->student->team->class_id); // update ff spending scoring
            $this->ffSpendingService->updateTotalScore(Auth::user()->student->team->class_id);

            //Update balance
            $team = Team::find($ffSpending->team_id);
            $this->teamService->updateBalance($team, $workingMoney);


            if ($survivingMonths >= $minimumMonth && $survivingMonths < 24) {
                $survivingMonthsAfterStagingDay = $survivingMonths - $minimumMonth;
                $survivingMonthsAfterStagingDayToMinute = $survivingMonthsAfterStagingDay * $monthToMinute;
                $outOfMoney = new OutOfMoney();
                $outOfMoney->team_id = Auth::user()->student->team_id;
                $outOfMoney->stage = OutOfMoney::$FF_SPENDING;
                $outOfMoney->is_running_out_of_money_on_deal_day = 1;
                $outOfMoney->month = $survivingMonthsAfterStagingDay;
                $outOfMoney->minutes = $survivingMonthsAfterStagingDayToMinute;
                $outOfMoney->monthly_cost = $quartlyCosts;
                $outOfMoney->save();
            } else {
                $outOfMoney = new OutOfMoney();
                $outOfMoney->team_id = Auth::user()->student->team_id;
                $outOfMoney->stage = OutOfMoney::$FF_SPENDING;
                $outOfMoney->is_running_out_of_money_on_deal_day = 0;
                $outOfMoney->monthly_cost = $quartlyCosts;
                $outOfMoney->save();
            }
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Success', 'success' => true, 'status' => 200, 'data' => $ffSpending]);
        } else {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'Error', 'success' => false, 'status' => 500, 'data' => null]);
        }
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'Validation Failed', 'success' => false, 'status' => 400, 'data' => array('class' => $ffSpendingRules)]);
    }
```

Note: if I change the function and make it simple, like return 'test', it does not show anymore that origin access error.
I wonder if there is any problem with function, why does not it show the actuall error, but it show that cors error instead.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Are you unintentionally making a cross-domain request?  If not where are your CORS definitions?  I don't think the PHP code you provide relates to the problem.

Comment: I do have a cors.php into the config folder like:

'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],

It is a Laravel Framework used

Comment: The most strange thing is that, if I remove all that code and make the function simpler like just return a simple string, it will work fine.... It seems odd to me, if its related to CORS it should still appear the same error even with a simple string returned...

Comment: One thing that is concerning me also is that, my site requires at least PHP Version 5.6 and on my go daddy shared hosting I have 5.5.x .. I cannot upgrade it due limits.

Answer (score -1):

What's happening is an ORIGINS request is coming in and getting declined because it's not in your allowed methods.

```
'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'ORIGINS']
```

You'll also want to set your `allowedOrigins` to something.

I always use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for reference.

Comment: I added this, and no changes, still the same problem :s

Comment: I am wondering why if I simplify the function to return only simple integer, works all fine, no problem with Origins or anything else...

Comment: I mean if it is something wrong with the code why does not it show the actuall code error but it shows allowed origin error...

Comment: Your browser is making an ORIGINS request (instead of GET, POST, etc.) and your server is responding that it's not allowed.  So it's not running the PHP you've posted. I don't know any more about your cors.php file or whatever framework it's configuring without more information.